# SSRS calculating IF THEN ELSE with nulls

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create a calculated field in an SSRS dataset but the fields that need to summed also have nulls and I can't get the formula correct.  Below is a description of what I am trying to do

```
If value.field1 = 1 and value.field2 is not null, then
    use value.field2
otherwise
    use value.field3
```

I am sure there is a simple answer to this, but I am very new to SSRS and can't seem to find the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to do something like this. This will check the value of field1 and the boolean value of whether or not field2 is null.

```
iif(fields!field1.value = 1 and isnothing(fields!field2.value) = 0, fields!field2.value, fields!field3.value)
```

The iif() statement is SSRS is structured in this way:

iif(conditional logic , executed if evaluated true, executed if evaluated false)

Comment: Thank you! That worked beautifully. But what if I wanted to do something to the following effect?   If field 1 is null or 0 then blank otherwise (field1-field2)

Comment: you would just need to do something along the lines of  `=iif( isnothing(fields!field1.value) = 1 or fields!field1.value = 0, "", (fields!field1.value - fields!field2.value))`

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  Comes back with an error#.  I  may not have explained correctly.  Let me try this again :-)  IF Field3 is null or = 0 then populate field with blank, otherwise subtract Field3 from Field4

Comment: this might be better suited to be a switch statement try something like this   `=switch(isnothing(fields!field3.value) = 1, "" ,fields!field3.value = 0,"" , fields!field3.value <> 0, fields!field4.value - fields!field3.value)`

Comment: also can you post the expression that you ended up using and error that it generated?

Comment: Below is a sample dataset. Using the =switch(isnothing(fields!field3.value) = 1, "" ,fields!field3.value = 0,"" , fields!field3.value <> 0, fields!field4.value - fields!field3.value) I get the following results:

Comment: Field1 Field2 Field3  Results
ROW1 0.97                          Error#
ROW2 678.55     230.25             -448.30                                                                                                  
Below is what I am trying to achieve                                                                                                        Field1 Field2 Field3  New CALC Field Desired Results
ROW1 0.97   
ROW2 245.48 763.10  517.62
ROW3 678.55 230.25  -448.30
ROW4 540                  0  -540.00
TOTAL 1465.00 993.35  -470.68

Comment: I am going to be honest you lost me there I am not able to follow what you are trying to say there. Start a nother question and post the actual code block and possibly a screenshot of the lay out so I can wrap my head around what you are trying to accomplish